# How can I loop through 2 MySQL tables but display based on each rows timestamp?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have 2 MySQL tables, one that I used to store comments and one that I use to store document file paths etc.

| CommentID | Comment | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | 02/08/2022 |

| DocumentID | FilePath | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | file.php | 04/08/2022 |

The above is a rough breakdown of my structure for each table and I want to loop through each table to display data but I want to be able to sort it by Timestamp and have it displayed like the image below so the comments and documents merge into 1 HTML table, how would I do this?

[image: HTML Table Design]

Comment: UNION the tables and then maybe have an outer query to order the whole lot by timestamp. Seems like a SQL issue, nothing to do with php or html

Comment: It seems to me that you need a table to display your output (comment, type, timestamp, detail_id) and then tables that hold the details (Comment, Document).  You could left join these tables on type and detail_id

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the SQL give you all the results already ordered, you could adjust your query to use UNION on the 2 tables, and ORDER BY Timestamp.

If you'd rather stick with separate SQL results for each table, consider using the datatables.net table library. It's free, easy to use, and you can set it to automatically sort your table by any column you specify. Has a lot of other useful features as well. I'd recommend using datatables.net tables even if you decide to get your results ordered in the SQL.

ALTERNATIVELY...
if you dont like either of these, and would like to sort the 2 result sets manually in your php, you can merge the 2 SQL result arrays, then use a `usort()` function...

So assuming your 2 SQL results look something like this:

```
$comments = array(
    array(
        'CommentID' => 1,
        'Comment' => 'One',
        'Timestamp' => '02/08/2022'
    ),
    array(
        'CommentID' => 2,
        'Comment' => 'Two',
        'Timestamp' => '05/08/2022'
    )
);
$documents = array(
    array(
        'DocumentID' => 1,
        'FilePath' => 'File 1',
        'Timestamp' => '04/08/2022'
    ),
    array(
        'DocumentID' => 2,
        'FilePath' => 'File 2',
        'Timestamp' => '03/08/2022'
    )
);
```

first merge the 2 arrays:

```
$rows = array_merge($comments, $documents);
```

now all the results are in 1 array.
next, create a `usort()` function to sort all the results by the value of the `Timestamp` key:

```
usort($rows, function($a, $b) {
    return (strtotime($a['Timestamp'])) - (strtotime($b['Timestamp']));
});
```

Now, the `$rows` variable looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CommentID] => 1
            [Comment] => One
            [Timestamp] => 02/08/2022
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DocumentID] => 2
            [FilePath] => File 2
            [Timestamp] => 03/08/2022
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DocumentID] => 1
            [FilePath] => File 1
            [Timestamp] => 04/08/2022
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CommentID] => 2
            [Comment] => Two
            [Timestamp] => 05/08/2022
        )

)
```

so all the data from both tables is sorted by timestamp, and you can just foreach through that `$rows` array and put each data set in your table

Comment: union and join are going to produce two completely different set of results and are not alternative. This scenario requires UNION.

Comment: @LelioFaieta looking more closely, you are probably right. These appear to be 2 completely different sets of data, so UNION would be required. And if the provided table structures show all columns of each table, then yes, it would need to be a UNION. Good catch. editing the answer...